# Generating Composite Index by PCA for a Single Country with Many Variables

Tags: time-series, pca, factor-analysis, dimensionality-reduction, composite

I am doing a course project where I am trying to generate an index to measure the overall level of prosperity of a single country - such as the United States. What I hope is that this index could be calculated on a quarterly basis, so that I can observe changes over time with enough data points.

I have collected around 100 variables for this country over the past 15 years (that is 60 quarterly data points, although some data are only updated annually). Some variables are economic data like GDP, and others represent societal conditions, such as population, number of traffic accidents, and length of public roads.

I am trying to use the information from these variables to build a single composite index. After reviewing how some indexes are constructed, I thought to first divide the 100 variables into four large categories (around 25 variables each) and then have five small subcategories (around 5 variables each).

I then thought about using principal component analysis (PCA) to build a single index for each subcategory. From there, I could use the five subcategory indexes and apply PCA again to generate a single index for each large category. This would give me four indexes for the four large categories, from which I could finally generate a single overall index.

However, in looking more closely at how PCA is used to generate indexes, it seems many entities (like GDP data for multiple countries) are generally needed for a valid PCA test. My question is: in my situation where I only have data for one country, can I still reasonably apply PCA based on the 60 quarterly time points? Does the process I've proposed seem valid? Thank you!